# How to create a multi-seat with one graphics card (having three DisplayPorts / HDMI)?

Tags: linux, gpu, multiseat

I am planning to build a reasonably powerful PC, for my needs (scientific calculations, as well as general computing needs; no gaming).

And I will have a couple of collaborators coming to join me.

I have realized it could be useful to have a multi-seat Linux operating system. If I understand correctly, a multi-seat operating system allows all users to work independently (with their own monitor, mouse and keyboard) and concurrently.

However, when I look for documentation, I see lots of old webpages, and the information is a bit confusing (to me, at least).

For example, I read the statement that each user needs a graphics card. But for example, if we have a single GPU, and this GPU had 3 DisplayPorts (or HDMI), couldn't this GPU be used for the three users? Note: I have read Zephyr allows to have a multi-seat with a single GPU, but I want to avoid third-party applications, I would like to rely only on Linux.

If it is not possible, has anybody tried a Threadripper (or any other board with enough PCIe lanes) with say 3 passive, low power GPU, like the nvidia GT 730 for example?

Edit: I have changed the word "multi-user" for "multi-seat", given a recommendation in the replies (thank you).

Comment: What you're asking for is called a *multi-seat* configuration, at least in the Linux world. Using that as a search keyword should produce better results.`Multi-user` covers everything from multiple remote logins, to old-style serial port terminals, to multi-seat configurations, and might result in a lot of false hits in your search.

Comment: This is possible with one graphics card, as outlined in https://askubuntu.com/questions/817982/. Using one graphics adapter per user is way easier to set-up, though. Have you looked in guides such as https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg_multiseat ?

Comment: Is it Zephyr or Xephyr?